# Switch statement for Coke Machine code

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have always used `if` `else` statements over `switch` statements, but I decided I wanted to try a switch out. I did the basic Coke Machine program with a switch and I cannot for the life of me figure out why it does not work how it should. When I use a number 1-5 for my input it continues to give the the switch default error message instead of the case cout statements (such as "You chose Coke"). Obviously something must be wrong that I am not seeing/

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;

    cout << "Beverage List" << endl;
    cout << "Coke = 1" << endl;
    cout << "Dr. Pepper = 2" << endl;
    cout << "Water = 3" << endl;
    cout << "Sprite = 4" << endl;
    cout << "Lemonade = 5" << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter a number to choose a beverage: ";
    cin >> number;

    switch (number)
    {
    case '1':
        cout << "You chose Coke";
        break;

    case '2':
        cout << "You chose Dr. Pepper";
        break;

    case '3':
        cout << "You chose Water";
        break;

    case '4':
        cout << "You chose Sprite";
        break;

    case '5':
        cout << "You chose Lemonade";
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Error: Choice was not valid. Here is your money back.";

    }

    cout << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lose the single quotes around all those case values.

Answer (score 2):

The character `'1'` is not the same as the number `1`.

Change

```
case '1':
```

to

```
case 1:
```

Comment: Oh well that makes total sense then. All of the switch statement examples I was viewing for tips were using chars, but I just assumed using the '' was just how you did a switch. Thank you for the quick and easy response.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your case statements are comparing chars, not integers:

```
case '5':
```

Try this instead:

```
case 5:
```